# how to run aws cli command to access aws bucket in JAVA

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface, aws-cli

AWS Access Key ID [****************]

AWS Secret Access Key [****************]

Default region name [us-east-1]

Default output format [json]: default output format

How to run AWS CLI via java code to copy object to aws bucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code for multiple commands at once:

```
public class DemoClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c command1 && command2 && command3");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access the AWS S3 bucket and perform operations on it using java then you don't need to use AWS cli

Instead you can easily do that and much more using [AWS Java SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/)

Following is the extract from AWS SDK page

> The SDK helps take the complexity out of coding by providing Java APIs
>   for many AWS services including Amazon S3, Amazon EC2, DynamoDB, and
>   more. The single, downloadable package includes the AWS Java library,
>   code samples, and documentation.

And if for some reason you just want to do that using the cli itself and call the cli command from Java then you can use the following example by simply changing the `awsCliCommand` value with the command that you want to run

```
public class MyAwsCliExec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String awsCliCommand = "aws s3 ls";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \""+awsCliCommand+"\"");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that using AWS's SDK, but I wanna run my code in java's Runtime class using AWS CLI.

Comment: Updated the answer on how to use Runtime class and AWS CLI to do that